# Pydev Django1.4 ImportError

Tags: django, pydev

I have an old Django project. I upgraded to Django 1.6 and I want to see if it still runs. I did all the upgrades like change url names, but I did not change the structure. It runs perfectly fine from the command line, but when I run it in Pydev I get

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'project.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named project.settings
```

What can I do to run it in Pydev?

Answer (score 1):

I have just experienced the same problem and the solution was to set the *Django settings module* in the project properties. Right click on the project, then click *Properties*, go to *PyDev - Django* and set the *Django settings module* text field's value to the desired settings file.